# What shall I do if I damage battery?

Tags: battery, hardware, broken-screen

I've been disassembling phone - Xiaomi Mi 5X/A1, in order to change crashed screen. However, while I was trying to remove battery, I probably cut battery cover, so I can see white slices and sharp smell is present (to remove battery I was just using playing card so I am very surprised that happened). Phone doesn't turn on and I am afraid it might explode (I really don't know but lithium is quite reactive). Is there any possibility to recover this phone? What shall I do with it?

Comment: As far as I know Lio batteries usually don't explode but they can set themself on fire. You can try to carefully remove the battery but make sure only to work where nothing is within range that could catch fire. Or place the phone in a closed metal box and bring it to a professional phone repair shop.

Comment: i guess this happened because of this glue stripes. buy new battery and replace diy https://youtu.be/J6M-WBbPAZM